# How do I change my skin manually?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ios

I have access to my iPhone's file system.

As stated in [this answer by me](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/224722/75275), it is a [confirmed bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-8752) where skins, when in the photo library, are converted straight into `.jpeg`, instead of the required `.png` format.

---

## How do I change my skin?

To simply put it: Which app folder directory do I upload the skin file into?

Also: **No, replacing the `char.png` located in the app package IS NOT THE ANSWER**, since nobody else can see that skin, except for you, as it's changing the default skin, rather than the player's custom skin, and **no, using the in-game skin changer is not an answer** as, in the first place, it does not work!

---

**Note:** This may have already been answered in a totally unrelated question somewhere. *I just can't seem to find it.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to change custom skins](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/222498/unable-to-change-custom-skins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Now I remember: [It was a comment on the bug tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-8752?focusedCommentId=245591&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-245591).

To change your Minecraft Skin manually on iOS, simply open a file system viewer and browse to the following folder:

```
.../[Minecraft PE]/Documents/game/com.mojang/minecraftpe/
```

And name it: `custom.png`.